# How to reset initialization in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytest, tensorflow2.0

If I try to change parallelism in TensorFlow 2 after initializing a `tf.Variable`,

```
import tensorflow as tf
_ = tf.Variable([1])
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

I get an error

> RuntimeError: Inter op parallelism cannot be modified after initialization.

I understand why that could be, but it (and possibly other factors) are causing my tests to interfere with each other. For example

```
def test_model():  # this test
   v = tf.Variable([1])
   ...

def test_threading():  # is breaking this test
   tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
   ...
```

How do I reset the TensorFlow state so that I can set the threading?

Answer (score 4):

This is achievable in a "hacky" way. But I'd recommend doing this the right way (i.e. by setting up config at the beginning).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.eager import context

_ = tf.Variable([1])

context._context = None
context._create_context()

tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

**Edit**: What is meant by setting up config at the beginning,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.eager import context

tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
_ = tf.Variable([1])
```

But there could be circumstances where you cannot always do this. Merely pointing out the conventional way of setting up config in `tf`. So if your circumstances don't allow you to fix `tf.config` at the beginning you have to reset your `tf.eager.context` as shown in the solution above.

Comment: can you elaborate on setting up a config at the beginning?

Comment: I was saying, first setting up all the necessary `tf.config` properties and then moving on to your computations. In your example it'll be first `tf.config.threading....` and `tf.Variable(...)`. But I understand that depending on your circumstances this might not be possible. Merely suggesting to stick to this format whenever it is possible.

Comment: i don't understand if (and how) what you're suggesting would clear the context. could you explain in your answer please? for example, I see no way to provide a context to `tf.config.threading` or `tf.Variable`

Comment: bear in mind i have no control over the order of execution of `tf config.threading...` vs `tf.Variable` : each call is in a separate test, with an order determined by the test runner

Comment: Yeah, as I said, then my first point is not applicable to you. But I was saying to have `tf.config` first and then your `tf` Graph related components and operations. But the solution I've posted should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the solution provided by @thushv89, we can also directly set the context by

```py
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
context.context().intra_op_parallelism_threads = <num_threads>
context.context().inter_op_parallelism_threads = <num_threads>
import tensorflow as tf
```

Details of the `get()` and `set()` thread function available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.14.0/tensorflow/python/framework/config.py#L146)